# Display different labels on different lines

Tags: c#, asp.net, label, multiline

I basically want the different labels to come on different lines.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label2.Text = Label3.Text + Label1.Text;
}
```

I want the `Label1.Text` to display on the line below `Label3.Text`.
I do not want to tweak the width and height cause the Text in the labels won't be of the same width in every label.

Comment: Use `\n` to declare a new line? `Label2.Text = Label3.Text + "\n" + Label1.Text;`

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of making sure the labels themselves are positioned appropriately?

Comment: I tried that along with \r\n, <br/> also Enviornment.Newline it doesn't work. Those are for test like "This is \r\n Text"

Comment: No not really cause basically Label2 is just adding the two labels and displaying the text within.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using `<br/>` in between it should work

```
Label2.Text = Label3.Text +"<br/>"+ Label1.Text;
```

Comment: Yes it worked thanks a lot! I had tried using <br/> before the + sign :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant approach:

```
Label2.Text = Label3.Text + Environment.NewLine() + Label1.Text;
```